# One of my variables is being set in initMap, but when I call another function inside the script that same variable is suddenly undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I original had this question posted, but wouldn't let me edit post nor resign in. In this I hope to have refocus and make it clear what I am asking for.

I define my map in the callback function of Google Maps Api. `initMap` is definitely being called first. Once it is I manually trigger the `addVehicleMarker` method.

This is how it is being called in HTML side:

```
// index.html

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
<script defer src="../src/map-manager.js"></script>
```

This is what I am doing in `initMap` below:

```
// map-manager.initMap

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: home_latlng,
    streetViewControl: false
});
```

### **My issue**

I want to import my `map-manager.js` class elsewhere. Mainly for the `addVehicleMarker` method. When I do the following...

```
var MapManager = require('../src/map-manager');
MapManager.addVehicleMarker(v);
```

`map` in `map-manager.js` is now undefined.
When I do...

```
addVehicleMarker(v);
```

`map` in `map-manager.js` has the map which I defined in `initMap`. Without my even having to import the file.

#### Question

How can I achieve the same thing in `addVehicleMarker(v);` while allowing my to import it properly and called it as `MapManager.addVehicleMarker(v);`, while retaining `map`?

#### This is the rest of the source:

```
// map-manager.js

var VehicleManager = require('../src/vehicle-manager');
var WampTasks = require('../src/wamp-tasks');

var map;
var vehicleMarkers = [];

function initMap() {
    const home_latlng = {
        lat: 33.816714399999995,
        lng: -117.90523610000001
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: home_latlng,
        streetViewControl: false
    });
}

// http://blog.mridey.com/2010/03/using-markerimage-in-maps-javascript.html
function addVehicleMarker(vehicle) {
    console.log(map);
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        vehicle.iconLocation,
        null, /* size is determined at runtime */
        null, /* origin is 0,0 */
        null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
        new google.maps.Size(32, 32)
    );
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: vehicle.currentLatLng,
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
    console.log(marker);
    // marker.setTitle(String(vehicle.displayName));

    vehicleMarkers.push(marker);
    console.log(vehicleMarkers);
}

module.exports = {};
module.exports["addVehicleMarker"] = addVehicleMarker;
```

Comment: Doing some testing. Everything in the file seems to be in a global scope. all function can be accessed by just referring to the name. I have tried using `exports` and `module.exports` to properly expose the variables when calling the methods, but I still end up with `map` being undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a var scope issue.  Declare var map at window  level   (and remove if presente other nested `var maps;` delacration

```
<script>
  var map;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: home_latlng,
    streetViewControl: false
 });
 ....
</script>
```

Comment: Uh, it worked. Why is it that worked? I tried making it scope related within the files and to all those who import it and try to access it.

Comment: This work because maps must be a var in common between all the element (function and object) that need accessing map .. otherwise you should pass the var in each function you need .. And if you redeclare var map in some function you simply override the gloabl function with a local function .. hope my comment is clear ..

Comment: Is there no notion of OOP structure for javascript type objects or is mainly the case because it is important a script at runtime?

Comment: Javascript is based  on prototype and not on class .. so there are some important difference .. .. i repeat yìif you need the map var in different script the simple way is declare the var at window level (top) level .. otherwise you can define a prototype object (somthings like a class) and assing at this proptotype  .. attribute include a map  attribute and access o passing to the istance of the prototype .. but this si another question  and require a general description of modelling application with javascript  then i hope my answer is rights and useful and in this case i hope you rate it